# How do I find out which language some Unicode characters belong to?

Tags: encoding, language, unicode, special-characters, utf-8

On Facebook, there are currently messages floating around with these strange chars:

> ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

They are used to confuse the reader, because they break out of the designated text areas.

Do they really belong to a language? If so, which one?

Comment: Was tempted to put it in the title, but didn't want to break the SE design. Would it work anyway?

Comment: They also break the preview for this post.

Comment: They belong to Thai. None of them are actual words.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are Thai characters with long strings of combining diacritic marks after base characters. You do quite similar things with Latin letters, too, e.g. â̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂ (which is a with circumflex followed by several combining circumflexes). Or you could use a sequence of combining horns: ư̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛ or cedillas: ç̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧̧. It naturally depends on rendering software how the contrived sequences will be displayed.

Comment: Okay, [what the …](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mRkE7.png) did you just do to this post of yours? :P

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux, you can try the Perl script [utfinfo.pl](http://sdaaubckp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/single-scripts/utfinfo.pl) (see also [Program to check/look up UTF-8/Unicode characters in string on command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/581523/program-to-check-look-up-utf-8-unicode-characters-in-string-on-command-line)); the output I get is:

```
$ echo ก็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้้้  | perl utfinfo.pl
Got 64 uchars
Char: 'ก' u: 3585 [0x0E01] b: 224,184,129 [0xE0,0xB8,0x81] n: THAI CHARACTER KO KAI [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: '็' u: 3655 [0x0E47] b: 224,185,135 [0xE0,0xB9,0x87] n: THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU [Thai]
Char: ' ' u: 32 [0x0020] b: 32 [0x20] n: SPACE [Basic Latin]
Char: 'ก' u: 3585 [0x0E01] b: 224,184,129 [0xE0,0xB8,0x81] n: THAI CHARACTER KO KAI [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: 'ิ' u: 3636 [0x0E34] b: 224,184,180 [0xE0,0xB8,0xB4] n: THAI CHARACTER SARA I [Thai]
Char: ' ' u: 32 [0x0020] b: 32 [0x20] n: SPACE [Basic Latin]
Char: 'ก' u: 3585 [0x0E01] b: 224,184,129 [0xE0,0xB8,0x81] n: THAI CHARACTER KO KAI [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
Char: '้' u: 3657 [0x0E49] b: 224,185,137 [0xE0,0xB9,0x89] n: THAI CHARACTER MAI THO [Thai]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just search for them on Google. E.g. ก  is Thai.

Answer (score 0):

According to some very brief Google work, Google Translate believes they are Thai characters; which from the style looks about right.

Answer (score 0):

Entering those characters in the search box on [Graphmenica](http://graphemica.com/) will take you to [this page](http://graphemica.com/search?q=%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87+%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4+%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89), showing the different characters being used:

- [ก  thai character ko kai (Unicode code point: U+0E01)](http://graphemica.com/%E0%B8%81)
- [ิ  thai character sara i (Unicode code point: U+0E34)](http://graphemica.com/0E34)
- [็  thai character maitaikhu (Unicode code point: U+0E47)](http://graphemica.com/0E47)
- [้  thai character mai tho (Unicode code point: U+0E49)](http://graphemica.com/0E49)