# Why does certain characters draw horribly, horribly wrong in Windows?

Tags: windows, characters

Odd characters:

> ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้

**Question:** Why does these characters draw so odd when you look at them in Windows*?

Here's a snippet from Outlook for you lucky bastards who aren't forced to use Windows:

[image: Stuff]

**Related:** [What's the character encoding used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310177/whats-the-character-encoding-used)

*Windows as in the OS. Applications drawing text using GTK+ and the likes doesn't show these like something out of an ***LSD-trip gone wrong***.

Comment: Are you saying that on your Windows machine, the characters that you typed in the question look like the characters in the image?  Because the typed characters look fine on my Windows machine.

Comment: Your question contains an unsubstantiated claim -- that Windows draws them "wrong". It would help if you stated how you think they should be drawn and what specifically is wrong with the way Windows draws them.

Comment: I'd be curious to see how the other OS'es handle this, I only see how Windows does it and to me that seems "right".

Comment: @dsolimano: on my Windows 7 box, running Firefox, the characters in his question appear as shown in the picture.

Comment: @Mokubai: you would expect characters on different lines to overlap?

Comment: Interesting, I'm on XP and it looks as you expect it to look in Firefox, Opera, and IE.  Must be a Vista/7 change.

Comment: **RELATED**: [͈̤̘͉ͦ̍͗ͯ͋ͅZ̴̷̲̬̤̣̟̈́̏̾ͧ̈͘A̼̘̫͋ͣͥͫͥ͡L͈͉͓̻͆̓ͣ͌ͅͅG̮̮͓̰͚̣͒̔͋̽ͯO̢̝ͦ͋̋ͮͮ͛ͬ̔͢!̷̩͚̝̖͇͑̒̆̊͢](http://eeemo.net/)

Comment: Also related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character

Comment: Patterns like this usually get posted by a person somewhere, after which someone picks it up and posts it on more popular forums and/or image boards after which it travels around the web. This isn't the first occurrence but I know it has started to spread (at least wild spread) around 17 February, if you want to find the public occurences. [This short URL](http://bit.ly/zW4xEu) refers to a Google query for half the string, as the full string is too large for Google to handle...

Answer (score 10):

As I seem to have taken a bit of a hit for thinking that Windows is "doing it right" I feel I should post an answer to justify my position.

The fact of the matter is that the text you have is telling the operating system to render an insane amount of combining characters.  The problem that one operating system actually renders them while another does not is due to a number of issues.  One of these issues is how **thorough** the programmers were when they wrote the code to render them, another would be due to programmers being too lazy to implement them properly, if at all.

Basically it comes down to the idea that written languages are fluid things, and that many characters in certain languages have multiple different [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) that get applied to modify the pronunciation of characters.  How do we handle all these diacritics, do we give each letter with a diacritic a new character (which would result in one heck of a lot of new and nearly identical characters) or do we create a set of characters specifically *for* diacritics and reduce our overall alphabet?

Unicode gives us the scope to do both, but in doing so the programmers who have to render these diacritics have to deal with the fact that there are some characters that actually do have multiple diacritics, one above and one below, and then the programmer has to ask the question of just when do they stop.  They could limit it to two, and satisfy most people but ignore those who want or need three diacritics in order to write formally in their own language.

Microsoft, whether rightly or wrongly, decided to let the user decide just how many extra marks a person wants to use.  This path takes a rather good programmer and some tough rationalisation to follow through.  I fully support them in both allowing this *and* the fact that they do it *well*.

If those characters were missing on the other hand, I would want to know just why they were missing.  Was it a "we drop this on the floor after `x` diacritics" decision, or was it due to the programmers being too lazy to do it properly and potentially exposing me to some buffer overflow with code hidden in the diacritics getting passed out to be executed by the system?

The simple issue here is that by *actually rendering* those characters I can see that the system is doing exactly what it is told to do, rather than doing what it thinks is right or, worse, doing something ***potentially harmful***.

Comment: Or: Why does Windows draw horribly, horribly wrong characters so well?

Comment: Covering over someone else's text meets the criteria of "potentially harmful" in my book.  (Perhaps the message being covered up is important.)  Incidentally, my preferred solution would be some form of clipping rather than a limit on the number of diacritics.  (If there are really languages which use characters that overlap with characters on adjacent lines, I don't care to know about it!)

Comment: Further: since MS are unlikely to change this behaviour anytime soon, Facebook and other sites that accept user data are likely to try to sanitize the character set themselves in order to prevent pranksters from misusing this "feature".  Unfortunately, the sanitization process may well have undesirable side effects.  If Windows clipped the output this wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does these characters draw so odd when you look at them in Windows*?

Because Windows attempts to render large numbers of Unicode [combining characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) when your text contains them, even though no actual script would ever combine that many marks together.

Comment: Presumably that means Windows is "doing it right" as per what is actually being asked of it rather than imposing limits on how many combining characters can be used.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/389333/how-do-i-find-out-which-language-some-unicode-characters-belong-to which seems to indicate that such tricks have gained popularity in Facebook.

Comment: @Mokubai: thing is, this is untrusted data - data coming from the internet.  Windows shouldn't necessarily do what untrusted data asks of it if it might not be in the best interests of the user.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I would be more worried if it *didn't* show all the diacritics, please see my answer.